# Scala AbstractMethodError

Tags: java, scala, sbt, actor

I've been using actors in my project for some time and everything was working great, then I added them to next file from project, and it stopped working.

This line:

```
actorSystem.actorOf(Props[GraphCreator])
```

compiles fine, but results in error (during runtime):

```
java.lang.AbstractMethodError
at akka.actor.ActorCell.create(ActorCell.scala:580)
at akka.actor.ActorCell.invokeAll$1(ActorCell.scala:456)
at akka.actor.ActorCell.systemInvoke(ActorCell.scala:478)
at akka.dispatch.Mailbox.processAllSystemMessages(Mailbox.scala:263)
at akka.dispatch.Mailbox.run(Mailbox.scala:219)
at akka.dispatch.ForkJoinExecutorConfigurator$AkkaForkJoinTask.exec(AbstractDispatcher.scala:393)
at scala.concurrent.forkjoin.ForkJoinTask.doExec(ForkJoinTask.java:260)
at scala.concurrent.forkjoin.ForkJoinPool$WorkQueue.runTask(ForkJoinPool.java:1339)
at scala.concurrent.forkjoin.ForkJoinPool.runWorker(ForkJoinPool.java:1979)
at scala.concurrent.forkjoin.ForkJoinWorkerThread.run(ForkJoinWorkerThread.java:107)
```

I'm using SBT as a compiler.

Comment: Which versions of Scala and Akka are you using for compiling and running your code? This might happen because you are compiling and / or running with incompatible versions. Does it happen only with one particular type of actor, or with all actors?

Comment: Actors in other places of project are working fine...
I have dependency: "com.typesafe.akka" %% "akka-actor" % "2.3.2"
About scala i'm not sure, probably version 2.10.3

Comment: I'm trying to create this actor inside another one. Can that have any influence on this error?

Comment: Why, AbstractMethodError is the new NullPointerException. Instead of turning runtime exceptions into compilation errors, it's the other way around. Is this a clean compile?

Comment: Yes, I tried sbt clean compile but it didn't change anything

Comment: you may check whether there's other library that depends on different akka version

Comment: Can you show output of `show runtime:dependencyClasspath` in all of your projects? How your `show libraryDependencies` look like? How do you start your program?